# cannot run python make_dataset.py -pylearn2 - training model

Tags: python, python-2.7, deep-learning, pylearn

I installed Pylearn2 and I want to train model using pylearn2. 
Reference　here: [enter link description here](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/tutorial/index.html#tutorial)

But I just run the Step 1: Create the dataset,  From the grbm_smd directory, run command $python make_dataset.py  , I got error:

$ python make_dataset.py

loading file /Users/k11067kk/pylearn2_data/cifar10/cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_1

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "make_dataset.py", line 27, in

```
train = cifar10.CIFAR10(which_set="train")
```

File "/Users/k11067kk/pylearn2/pylearn2/datasets/cifar10.py", line 73, in **init**

```
data = CIFAR10._unpickle(fname)
```

File "/Users/k11067kk/pylearn2/pylearn2/datasets/cifar10.py", line 257, in _unpickle

```
dict = cPickle.load(fo, encoding='latin-1')
```

TypeError: load() takes no keyword arguments

I did some tests and I set the Path like this : $export PYLEARN2_DATA_PATH=~/pylearn2_data
what wrong?  Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded dataset files?
You can download them by running pylearn2/scripts/datasets/download_cifar10.sh
Please try it.